# SFML platformer using c++

Tags: c++, sfml

Hey im currently making an sfml platformer and going to use map tiles however after implementing my map class it is coming up with an unhandled exception.
i call the initialise function first and then drawmap at the end. here is the code..

```
    void Map::Initialise(const char *filename)
{
     std::ifstream openfile(filename);
    if(openfile.is_open())
    {
        std::string tempLine;
        std::getline(openfile, tempLine);

        tempLine.erase(std::remove (tempLine.begin(), tempLine.end(), ' '), tempLine.end());
        MapX = tempLine.length();

        openfile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

        while(!openfile.eof())
        {

            openfile >> MapFile[loadCountX][loadCountY];
            loadCountX++;
            if(loadCountX >= MapX)
            {
                loadCountX = 0;
                loadCountY++;
            }
        }
        MapY = loadCountY;
    }

}

void Map::DrawMap(sf::RenderWindow &Window)
{
    sf::Shape rect = sf::Shape::Rectangle(0, 0, BLOCKSIZE, BLOCKSIZE, sf::Color(255, 255, 255, 255));
    sf::Color rectCol;
    for(int i = 0; i < MapX; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < MapY; j++)
        {
            if(MapFile[i][j] == 0)
                rectCol = sf::Color(44, 117, 255);
            else if (MapFile[i][j] == 1)
                rectCol = sf::Color(255, 100, 17);

            rect.SetPosition(i * BLOCKSIZE, j * BLOCKSIZE);
            rect.SetColor(rectCol);
            Window.Draw(rect);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file loop is bad, using an `eof` loop can caused undefined behavior and is generally a poor approach to file looping. Instead follow a loop of this structure:

```
fileIn >> data
//while fileIn object is good
while(fileIn) {
    //handle data variable
    fileIn >> data; //re-read data in
}
```

you want to manipulate and handle your data before reading in the next variable, you're doing just the opposite. Because of this your file reaches eof, but you attempt to read data one last time and handle it, which throws your exception.

Expanding on what i said above:

```
openfile >> MapFile[loadCountX][loadCountY];

//while your input stream is still good
while(openfile)
        {
        //handle your file data
            loadCountX++;
            if(loadCountX >= MapX)
            {
                loadCountX = 0;
                loadCountY++;
            }
        //now read in again AFTER
        openfile >> MapFile[loadCountX][loadCountY];
        }
```

should correctly read in and store data.

Comment: ahh thankyou i shall try that. I realised what I did wrong. I didnt give the loadcountX and Y a value when declaring. Also having a problem with the program just randomly closing for no reason what so ever.

Comment: I can help you with that a little later, make sure you mark this as solved and shoot me an email with your code @gmercer015@gmail.com so i can work with you on that other problem.